# MySQL: Returning results based on multiple rows in a different table

Tags: mysql

I'm having trouble with a complex MySQL query when trying to match a many-to-many relationship between two other tables.

If anyone could give me some help I'd be massively grateful!

**My Problem:**

I currently have 5 tables:

**industries**

```
+----+----------------------------------+
| ID | Name                             |
+----+----------------------------------+
| 1  | Accountancy, Banking and Finance |
+----+----------------------------------+
```

**users**

```
+----+-----------+--------------------+
| ID | Name      | Email              |
+----+-----------+--------------------+
| 1  | Joe Smith | joesmith@email.com |
+----+-----------+--------------------+
```

**jobs**

```
+----+-------------------+------------------+
| ID | Title             | Description      |
+----+-------------------+------------------+
| 3  | Financial Analyst | Example job desc |
+----+-------------------+------------------+
```

When registering, the user selects a number of industries that they are interested in working in. Since it is a many to one relationship, these preferences are then stored in a new table, user_interests, as a row for each industry the user is interested in.

**user_interests**

```
+----+--------+------------+
| ID | userID | industryID |
+----+--------+------------+
| 3  | 1      | 2          |
+----+--------+------------+
| 4  | 1      | 4          |
+----+--------+------------+
```

And when an employer creates a new job, they set multiple industries that the job is in. This is then saved in the same way, as multiple rows in the job_interests table.

**job_interests**

```
+----+-------+------------+
| ID | jobID | industryID |
+----+-------+------------+
| 3  | 2     | 2          |
+----+-------+------------+
| 4  | 2     | 3          |
+----+-------+------------+
```

When the user searches for a role, the query should return all jobs where the job_interests for that job match at least one user_interest for that user.

I'm unsure where to start with this problem, and if I have structured my database properly in the first place to accommodate for this type of search.

Any help with this problem would be massively appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Structure looks fine. learn the section on MySQL JOINs.

Comment: BTW, you are using many-to-many relationships, not many-to-one. As @danblack says, the structure looks fine, and simple joins should do the trick. If you have one that you are having trouble with, edit your question, and show the query.

Comment: Note that the surrogate PRIMARY KEY on your pivot tables isn't necessary; you could use the natural key instead